# How to get a list of historical payments for a subscription from Google Developer API?

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

By using Google Play Developer API and the call `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}` (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get) it is possible to get information about if the subscription is still valid.

How do I find out the `orderId` for each payment without guessing (by doing like this: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html)?
Is it possible to, through a service-account-call to the API, get all historical payments for a subscription for a user? (By using the purchaseToken and subscriptionId for example).

Comment: Did you find solution for it? Thanks

Comment: Nope, I am afraid not.